# Coverage Report with Jest and Vue not working

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

I am unit testing my Vue project with Jest and I get the code coverage in the console, no problems there, however the HTML report is not working -

[image]

package.json:

```
...
"unit": "jest --config test/unit/jest.conf.js --coverage",
...
```

jest.conf.js:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  verbose: true,
  testURL: "http://localhost/",
  rootDir: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../'),
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'js',
    'json',
    'vue'
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1'
  },
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.js$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest',
    '.*\\.(vue)$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/vue-jest'
  },
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/test/e2e'
  ],
  snapshotSerializers: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-serializer-vue'],
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/test/unit/setup'],
  mapCoverage: true,
  coverageDirectory: '<rootDir>/test/unit/coverage',
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    'src/**/*.{js,vue}',
    '!src/main.js',
    '!src/router/index.js',
    '!src/plugins/vuetify.js',
    '!**/node_modules/**'
  ]
}
```

What might be the cause of that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you're missing a `coverageReporters` property in your jest config. The default doesn't include html as a reporter.

Comment: @ShafiqJetha thank you, but I added `coverageReporters: ['json', 'lcov', 'text', 'clover', 'html'],` to my jest config and it's still not working.

Comment: Whwt happens if you just set it to html?

Comment: So it worked in terms of showing the lines that are not covered (what I actually wanted), but the overview is still empty. Maybe its a bug. Anyway, thats fine for me now. Thank you!

Comment: If I put this down as an answer, will you mark it as accepted?

Comment: Yes, go ahead!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your coverage report property might need to be adjusted. You should try including `html` in your `coverageReporters`, like this:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  coverageReporters: ['html']
  ...
}
```